# want to open editable image on browser in asp.net with VB

Tags: asp.net

I have directly call to mspaint.exe on button click but doesn.t open it is shows on task manager but not show on broser

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

1st, if you try to use ASP.NET server side code to invoke or open mspaint.exe it is going to open it on the server and not the browser.

2nd, you are not going to be able to launch a .exe on the client (obvious security reasons) and really can;t even count on them using MS Windows and have paint installed.

The better solution is just to open the image in a new browser window. If you want them to immdeatly edit it, you might have to have them download it 1st, make any modifications using the program of their choice, and then upload it back to your site.

Comment: Thanks for reply..
i have mspaint on my pc and i am using below code,...
Shell("C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe career3_201085634166394592765087.jpg")

Comment: ASP.NET runs under a differnet security context and will probably not have the ability to 'Shell' out or start a process. You will probably need to wrap the call (and you can use system.diagnostics.process.Start as an alternative to Shell) in Impersonation using an administrative account that has access to launch the mspaint.exe application.  See this link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx